# Trying to streamline button navigation in google sheets. It works but it's tedious and clunky. Anyway to automate this?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am building a VFX shot tracking database, based off of an existing paid software platform. I only use about 10% of the functionality of the paid app, so I'm trying to replicate that 10% in google sheets.

What I currently have:

2 tabs.

- Sheet1 is "FO_VFX_010"
- Sheet2 is "All_shots"

[image: example]

on Sheet1, "FO_VFX_010" A10 to A76 I currently have the command to look at "All_shots" to fill in the shot numbers **IE "**=All_shots!A2" **"**=All_shots!A3" **"**=All_shots!A4" etc.

The idea being, I can past in client shot numbers into the A column on "All_shots" and it will autofill the A column on "FO_VFX_010".

BUT, I also want A10 to A76 to be buttons.

I want to click on any of the entries in "FO_VFX_010" A10 to A76 and have it jump to a new sheet (this would be a duplicate of "FO_VFX_010".)

So click on "FO_VFX_020" it sends the command to jump to the tab/Sheet of the same name.

Currently I have the rather tedious work around of an invisible "drawing" with a script attached to it hovering over each cell.

The script, which I've had to manually duplicate and alter for EACH button is as follows:

```
function FO_VFX_020() {

// 1 = row 1, 14 = column 14 = N

goToSheet("FO_VFX_020", 1, 1);

}



function goToSheet(sheetName, row, col) {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);

SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);

var range = sheet.getRange(row, col)

SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);

}
```

This totally works. But I'm tearing my hair out manually duplicating and changing this 67 times. Also having to set permissions with 5 mouse clicks for EVERY single entry kind of sucks.

Is there ANY way to streamline this?

I'd love to ONLY enter the information in "All_shots" column A then have it feed into "FO_VFX_010" A10 to A76. then have each of those automatically be a button, that automatically points to their appropriate tabs/sheets. So that it's dynamic. As new shows come along, I can paste in the client info into "All_shots" and regardless of how many entries there are.... could be 300 let's say, it would auto propagate that info and functionality into "FO_VFX_010". Even better if the names could be anything.

Added functionality would be a conditional format rule.

I have a script running in a cell that queries the Sheetname and auto-fills in the shot name above the thumbnail. (C2) Then I have a conditional format so that all the shot names in the list of A10 to A76 look to see if the name in (C2) matches their name. If there's a match, it turns blue.

This, I'm sure is very convoluted. Mostly because I don't know what I'm doing. So I'm trying to throw things at the wall and see what sticks. I can't code. I just sort of hack and slash to make things work. but I've hit a wall on how to do this right so it can be automated.

Ultimately.. if there's a better way to do this so that it's all dynamic, then I can create a template of "FO_VFX_010" based off the info of "All_shots" have everything working, then duplicate "FO_VFX_010" rename it to "FO_VFX_020" and have everything update to the correct information/button pathing etc.

Currently this all works. But there's a whole obscene amount of manual copy and paste for every single button. I'm trying to streamline this so at the very least if I have more than 67 shots, I'm not making a new invisible button, linked to a script, that has to be altered on 2 lines, renamed, run, permissions accepted via 5 mouse clicks.. and then it works.

Also I'd love to figure out an automated way to take my existing "FO_VFX_010" once it all works and run a script to duplicate and rename is X number of times. if I have 67 shots, duplicate it and rename it 66 times. 300 shots 299 times etc.

I did find an existing custom script that does this, but it only does it one duplicate at a time.

```
function onOpen() {

var menu = [{name: "Duplicate and name", functionName: "dupName"}];

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", menu);

}



function dupName() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

var name = Browser.inputBox('Enter new sheet name');

ss.insertSheet(name, {template: sheet});

}
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

And it bears repeating.. I CANNOT CODE.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] This questions needs more focus. You might have to split you project in smaller parts or you might need to learn about the JavaScript / programming basics.

Comment: Okay, thing one: 

I need to streamline the code for the buttons. I have: function FO_VFX_020() {

// 1 = row 1, 14 = column 14 = N

goToSheet("FO_VFX_020", 1, 1);

}



function goToSheet(sheetName, row, col) {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);

SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);

var range = sheet.getRange(row, col)

SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);

} 

I need it to be somehow all encompassing so, if I have 5 buttons or 500 I can alter a list of filenames, have it look at the name in the cell and path it to the correct tab.

Comment: I know that you can tell a cell to be a hyperlink, but that brings up a popup that you then have to click through to wherever you're going. 

I'm trying to keep it clean. Click on the cell..it navigates to the correct tab.

Invisible buttons appear to solve this.. but as in my long post above.. it's a LOT of coding per button, and I want this to be scalable.